# EFI Partition (/boot/efi) shows 100% Usage, even it is not

Tags: debian, boot, partition, disk-usage, uefi

since a couple of days I ran into a strange „problem“. Using `df` in the console, it reports my `/dev/sda1` mounted in `/boot/efi` as nearly full

```
root@xxxxxxxxx:~# df -h 
Filesystem                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                   1.6G   12M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/xxxxxxxx--vg-root                32G   10G   21G  34% /
tmpfs                                   7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                   7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                   7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda2                               237M   92M  133M  41% /boot
/dev/sda1                               511M  510M  1.9M 100% /boot/efi                   <--------- This line
folder2ram                              7.8G   29M  7.8G   1% /var/log
folder2ram                              7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /var/tmp
folder2ram                              7.8G  880K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/openmediavault/rrd
folder2ram                              7.8G  1.2M  7.8G   1% /var/spool
folder2ram                              7.8G   22M  7.8G   1% /var/lib/rrdcached
folder2ram                              7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/monit
folder2ram                              7.8G  1.3M  7.8G   1% /var/cache/samba
```

However, Checking with `du`, or `gparted` reports something completed different:

```
root@xxxxxxxx:~# du -sh /boot/efi/
5.2M    /boot/efi/
```

The list of all files only Show a few:

```
root@xxxxxxx:~# sudo du -h /boot/efi | sort -n | tail -10
4.0K    /boot/efi/EFI/INTEL
5.1M    /boot/efi/EFI/debian
5.2M    /boot/efi
5.2M    /boot/efi/EFI
```

I already purged old Kernels and also did `apt-get autoremove` and rebooted a couple of times. Nothing helped so far.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lsof -n | grep /boot/efi | grep deleted`

Comment: `root@xxxxxxxxxxx:/# lsof -n | grep /boot/efi | grep deleted root@ xxxxxxxxxxx:/# `

So the result is empty ....

I have to say that a couple of days ago I run the same command and resulted in 

`lsof no pwd entry for uid xxx`

I then created a user with the respective uid and the error is now gone.

Comment: Try to reboot please.

Comment: I did this already but now did it again. No change ...

Comment: `umount` the partition run `fsck` on it

Comment: I have done this. You can see the output in the comments of the next answer. Short version: nothing changed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
`fsck -a -v /dev/sda1`

FAT filesystem breaks a lot and I hate the idea that it's used for EFI partition. It should be automatically fixed on boot by systemd service but maybe your setup is different.

Comment: Should it be dosfsck or fsck.fat as fsck is for the ext2, ext3 & ext4 family of formats. See man dosfsck or man fsck.vfat which all open man page for fsck.fat.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I executed the command and also rebooted. Situation is unchanged. Here is the output of the command: `root@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~# fsck.vfat -a -v -V /dev/sda1  fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24) Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem Boot sector contents: System ID "mkfs.fat" Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)        512 bytes per logical sector       4096 bytes per cluster         32 reserved sectors First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)          2 FATs, 32 bit entries     524288 bytes per FAT (= 1024 sectors) Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size) `

Comment: Second part: `Data area starts at byte 1064960 (sector 2080)     130812 data clusters (535805952 bytes) 63 sectors/track, 255 heads       2048 hidden sectors    1048576 sectors total Starting check/repair pass. Reclaiming unconnected clusters. Checking free cluster summary. Starting verification pass. Checking for unused clusters. /dev/sda1: 46 files, 130331/130812 clusters  `

Comment: @oldfred my fsck recognizes the filesystem format and directs to correct executable.
gadric please check out hidden directories with ls -la or ncdu.

Comment: I have already done this before. No hidden directories. The output: `boot/efi/EFI:
total 16
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Oct 25 10:51 .
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Jan  1  1970 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Oct 25 10:51 INTEL
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 16 18:18 debian

/boot/efi/EFI/INTEL:
total 8
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Oct 25 10:51 .
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Oct 25 10:51 ..
-rwx------ 1 root root    0 Oct 25 10:51 FNCML357.CAP`

Comment: Second part: `
/boot/efi/EFI/debian:
total 5220
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 May 16 18:18 .
drwx------ 4 root root    4096 Oct 25 10:51 ..
-rwx------ 1 root root     108 Aug  2 11:33 BOOTX64.CSV
-rwx------ 1 root root 1206824 Aug  2 11:33 fbx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root     121 Aug  2 11:33 grub.cfg
-rwx------ 1 root root 1533296 Aug  2 11:33 grubx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1261192 Aug  2 11:33 mmx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1322936 Aug  2 11:33 shimx64.efi`

However, I have realized that after `fsck` there are a lot of **FSCK00XX.REC** files.

Comment: **Update**: I think and hope I got the problem solved. I move all FSCK00XX.REC files away and now the output of `df -h` is much more reasonable. I guess I had a corrupt filesystem and with fsck it was repaired and it was saved to the files. Since my partition was working, I (hopefully) do not need these files.